# Is there a quick way to get unique properties in an IEnumerable collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, razor

So I have this collection of items in my razor page view I display these items in a table like so:

```
       @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
            <tr class="itemsRow">
                <td class="">
                    <a asp-controller="Catalog" asp-action="ProductPage" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                        <img src="@item.ImageUrl" class="imageCell" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="">@item.Title </td>
                <td class="">@item.Category </td>
                <td class="">@item.Sku </td>
                <td class="">@item.Location </td>
                <td class="">@item.Available </td>
                <td class="">@item.Notes </td>
            </tr>
            }
```

Each item in the list belongs to a category @item.Category and multiple items can belong to the same category. I want to create a drop down menu filled with the unique categories so if a user selects one of the categories the page will filter the items by that category.

I was going to put the categories in a list in a really ugly way and do something like

```
listOfCategories = new list;
foreach(item in Model.Items){
  foreach(addedCategories in listOfCategories{
  //if item.category isn't in the list of categories then add it to the list
  }
}
```

is there a better way to do this? I'm not super worried about performance because the categories should be less than 20 for 99% of the users but it's just so ugly I don't want to code it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.Linq` to return the `Distinct` categories from the list of items:

```
var categories = Model.Items.Distinct(item => item.Category);
```

And then when the user chooses a category, you can get the items using:

```
var categoryItems = Model.Items.Where(item => item.Category == selectedCategory);
```